# Can you use "nek" in other ways than "nek... nek..." (neither...nor...)?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "nek" in the way that neither is used in the following English contexts:

"Do you want a chocolate or a strawberry milkshake?"
"Neither. I want vanilla."

and

"I could not stop him from talking. Neither could I avoid hearing what he said."

In other words, can I use "nek" on its own in a sentence, without an accompanying "nek" in another clause?

Answer (score 4):

Your second example is a paragon for the single *nek*. *Nek* [means](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neado.html#i-nzv) *kaj ankaŭ ne*.

> Mi ne povis deteni lin de parolado. Mi nek povis eviti aŭdi kion li diris.

For your other example one would say

> Ĉu vi volas ĉokoladon aŭ fragon? Nek, nek. Mi volas vanilon.

according to [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/nek_nek.html).

But I'm pretty sure that a single *nek* is also perfectly understandable.

> Ĉu vi volas ĉokoladon aŭ fragon? Nek. Mi volas vanilon.

---

<sub>I don't know what milkshake is in Esperanto.</sub>

Comment: A single `nek` is not understandable. As for "nek, nek" I hear people use more often either "neniun" or "neniun el la du".

Comment: I would say “mi nek povis eviti aŭdi…”. Otherwise if you say “nek mi” it sounds like you are saying “ne nur vi ne povis deteni lin, ankaŭ mi ne povis”, but that wouldn’t make sense for the example.

Comment: @NeilRoberts Isn't that also true for the english version? I think that's a matter of taste. I'm not even sure if *ne nur vi ...* really wouldn't make sense in the example (but I'm not native En). Depends on emphasis, doesn't it? If *ne nur vi ne povis deteni lin, ankaŭ mi ne povis* doesn't make sense, context clarifies the meaning and I would prefer to start with *nek* in the sense of *nek: ...*.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani So if someone would answer the question *Ĉu vi volas ĉokoladon aŭ fragon?* with *Nek. Mi volas vanilon.* you wouldn't understand that *nek* is just short for *nek, nek*? That's hard to believe.

Comment: Neil pravas. There is a principle in Esperanto of putting a modifier just before the modified word. Thus _nek mi povis eviti…_" means neither you nor I couldn't avoid. _mi nek povis eviti…_ means "I could neither stop nor avoid hearing".

Comment: I only thought about spoken communication. In written language where you don't have emphasis, it should really be *mi nek povis* instead of *nek mi povis* to make clear what *nek* refers to. Thanks @NeilRoberts for the note!

Comment: @Olafant, a single "nek" could be understandable (probably heard as a simple incorrect "ne"). I offer you a parallel situation: if I wanted both chocolate and strawberry, the answer would be, colloquially, "kaj kaj". A single "kaj" would not make any sense, the original is "kaj A kaj B", so you abbreviate it to just "kaj kaj". If the original is "nek A nek B", using just a single "nek" to abbreviate it is really weird _for me_. "nek nek" would be ok. But that's just my opinion based on hearing native speakers a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
Can you use “nek” in other ways than “nek… nek…” (neither…nor…)?
```

Yes, it can also follow a negative part of a sentence. It is not really that different from "_nek... nek..." though:

```
mi nenion havas kontraŭ la enpreno de la novaj vortoj,
nek kontraŭ la elĵeto de kelkaj vortoj
```

(Lingvaj Respondoj, Zamenhof)

`nek` does not **ever** stand alone. It must either follow a negative (part of a) sentence, as above, or another `nek` or be part of the `nek… nek…` structure. In the **same** sentence.

That's because the meaning is `ankaŭ ne`, so it needs to have a relation with something else, that has already been said.

So, this sentence in another answer:

```
Mi ne povis deteni lin de parolado. Mi nek povis eviti aŭdi kion li diris.
```

should be either just one sentence (*nek* belongs to *povi*):

```
Mi ne povis deteni lin de parolado, nek eviti aŭdi kion li diris.
```

or two sentences (with *ankaŭ ne*):

```
Mi ne povis deteni lin de parolado. Mi ankaŭ ne povis eviti aŭdi kion li diris.
```